# How to call an image from a database using Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I hope someone can help.

I am doing a college assignment at the moment, where I am building a website for purchasing cups/t shirts with a meme of their choice to be put on the cup/t-shirt.

Please excuse my lack of code here, as I am just starting it and I am looking for help on the direction I should do this.

At the moment I have all images in my images folder, and I have a record for each meme in my database with the image location. This is my meme table. Ignore the positive/negative fields as this is for a user to up or down vote a meme (Spec requirement)

```
    CREATE TABLE `memes` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `image` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `postive` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `negative` int(15) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    sample data = (1, 'baby', 'images/baby.jpg', '0', '0'),
```

I have a page now where the user is presented with a blank white cup, and they will be given a list of the memes where they can choose which one is to be placed on the cup. I am doing this by javascript and it will look a bit like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function main(value)
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainColour").src = "images/dog.jpg";

    }
    else if (value == 2)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainColour").src = "images/disney.jpg";

    }
    else if (value == 3)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainColour").src = "images/baby.jpg";

    }
    else if (value == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainColour").src = "images/waiting.jpg";

    }

    else if (value == 5)
    {
        document.getElementById("mainColour").src = "images/duck.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<h1> Design your cup! </h1>
<div id = "page">
<div id = "middle">

<img src="images/basecup.jpg" width="450" height="450" alt="shoe"id="base"/>
<div id="cupmeme"><img src="images/blank.png" width="150"    height="150"alt="shoe" id="mainColour"/></div>
</div>

<div id = "leftMenu">

<p>Which meme would you like??</br>
    <input type="radio" name="main" id = "colourMain" onclick="main(this.value)" value="1" checked >Blue
    <input type="radio" name="main" id = "colourMain" onclick="main(this.value)" value="2">Green
    <input type="radio" name="main" id = "colourMain" onclick="main(this.value)" value="3">Pink ( + EUR 5.00)
    <input type="radio" name="main" id = "colourMain" onclick="main(this.value)" value="4">Red
    <input type="radio" name="main" id = "colourMain" onclick="main(this.value)" value="5">Brown
</p>
```

At the moment I am calling the images from the folder images, but our lecture is requiring us to call this from the database instead. I have a Model and Controller set up but nothing is on them yet.

Can anyone advise? Apologies if this isn't clear. Last assignment of the year so I am really eager just to get this done.

Thanks a lot,

Killian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use services to host images for you? Then I would look into something like http://cloudinary.com/, or Amazon S3 buckets, and store the image link in my memes table.

Or you could go the binary route, and store each image as binary data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing an image URL in your database already(?), which is fine. Without writing the entire thing for you, you'll probably want to look at creating a method to grab an image based on ID (effectively what your JavaScript is doing).

So, instead of the big if statement in JavaScript you could run a single AJAX call (look into jQuery load) which would take an ID, and give you back the image URL.

That way, you could use what's stored in your database, rather than manually writing out HTML and JavaScript.